# Higher homotopy groups equality question.

Tags: proof-explanation, higher-homotopy-groups

I'm self learning Algebraic Topology from Rotman's Algebraic Topology and I've come across this:

How are these two expressions in the red box equal?  I understand how $\Sigma ^nS^0 = S^n$, but I don't see how the next relationship is possible.

Anyone have any ideas?  Please be explicit as I am self learning this.

[image]

Comment: Just that $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$ are adjoint functors: $[\Sigma Y,X]$ is naturally equivalent to $[Y,\Omega X]$.

Comment: But why are they equal?  Doesn't an adjoint relationship just say there's a bijection between the two sets?

Comment: It's an "abuse of notation".

Comment: So what would be a proper use of notation for that relationship?

Comment: They're iso.  These are homotopy classes of maps, not strict sets of maps.

Comment: @Randall "Iso" as in they're isomorphic groups?

Comment: The equation $[S^n, X] = [\Sigma^n S^0, X]$ is also suspect! (unless you *define* $S^n$ in such a way as to be equal to $\Sigma^n S^0$ rather than merely homeomorphic) Really, most of these equal signs are representing natural isomorphisms rather than equality.

Comment: But how specifically are these two groups isomorphic?  What properties show this relationship?  How does the adjointness of the two functors show this particular relationship?

Comment: Yes, iso as groups.  To understand why they are groups, look up H spaces.

Comment: I understand why they are groups, but I don't understand how the two groups are isomorphic.  What about the fact that the functors are adjoint imples that these two groups are isomorphic?  I don't see how I can show $[\Sigma^n S^0, X] \approx [\Sigma^{n-k}S^0, \Omega^k X]$.